# Cannot setup the Datastore in jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-datastore

I make a simple datastore to store a long value.

In **UserPreferencesRepository.kt**

```
class UserPreferencesRepository(
    private val dataStore: DataStore<Preferences>
) {
    private companion object {
        val TIME_START = longPreferencesKey("time_start")
        const val TAG = "UserPreferencesRepo"
    }

    suspend fun saveTimePreference(theTime : Long){
        dataStore.edit { preferences ->
            preferences[TIME_START] = 0L
        }
    }

    val dateTime: Flow<Long> = dataStore.data
        .catch {
            if (it is IOException) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error reading preferences.", it)
                emit(emptyPreferences())
            } else {
                throw it
            }
        }
        .map { preferences ->
            preferences[TIME_START] ?: 0L
        }
}
```

And then add this to my viewmodel.

in **HomeViewModel.kt**

```
class HomeViewModel(
    private val userPreferencesRepository: UserPreferencesRepository
) : ViewModel() {
   // Implemented nothing yet
}
```

That stages, the code is working just fine, but when I add this view model to my composables, it get crushed.

I tried this way,

```
@Composable
fun HomeScreen(
){
    val viewModel = viewModel<HomeViewModel>()
}
```

and this way,

```
@Composable
fun HomeScreen(
   homeViewModel: HomeViewModel = viewModel()
){
   
}
```

The app gets crushed whenever I do this.
the error says that

```
Cannot create an instance of class com.playmakers.lifemetrics.ui.screens.home.HomeViewModel
```

How can I solve this problem, or suggest me the correct way of doing it.

Comment: Please include the entire stack trace of the exception.

Answer (score 1):

Your ViewModel needs the instance of `UserPreferencesRepository` which you declared as a constructor parameter. But You are calling viewModel() function without the repository instance, that's why it's unable to instantiate your HomeViewModel class.
To solve this instantiation problem, you have to provide repository instance to your viewModel class so that it can be instantiated.
You can create a Factory class like below:

```
class HomeViewModelFactory(
    private val repository: UserPreferencesRepository
): ViewModelProvider.Factory {

    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        return HomeViewModel(repository) as T
    }
}
```

Now, you can get the instance of your ViewModel class by passing factory instance like below:

```
@Composable
fun HomeScreen(){
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val repository = UserPreferencesRepository(context.dataStore)

    val viewModel = viewModel(HomeViewModel::class.java, factory = HomeViewModelFactory(repository))
}
```